# Execute one method in one test tag in parallel in testng

Tags: java, multithreading, selenium-webdriver, testng

This is my class containing test method which I want to execute in parallel.
Each input from Data Provider is a new thread.
When I execute this method in 2 threads as Data Provider has 2 inputs, test hangs in one browser and other executes

```
public class DemoTest {
private static final ThreadLocal<WebDriver> webDriverThreadLocal= new InheritableThreadLocal<>();    
private String baseUrl;
private String severity;

@BeforeMethod
public void beforeMethod() {
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    webDriverThreadLocal.set(driver);
    System.out.println("In before method:"+Thread.currentThread().getId());
    System.out.println("FF hashcode:"+driver.hashCode());
}

@DataProvider(name = "data-provider", parallel=true)
public Object[][] dataProviderMethod() throws IOException {
    System.out.println("On dp");
    new Object[] { 1, "a" },
  new Object[] { 2, "b" },

}

public  void testProgramOptions(Integer n, String s) {
     WebDriver driver = webDriverThreadLocal.get();
     baseUrl = "http://www.google.com/";
     driver.get(baseUrl);
     System.out.println("method f id:"+Thread.currentThread().getId()+" n:"+n+" s:"+s);
     //test continues
}

@AfterMethod
public void afterMethod() {
    WebDriver driver = webDriverThreadLocal.get();
    System.out.println("In after method for id:"+Thread.currentThread().getId());
    driver.quit();
}
}
```

This is testng.xml

```
 <suite name="Suite" parallel="methods"> 
 <test name="prelogin" >
  <classes>

       <class name="DemoTest"></class>

  </classes>
  </test>
  </suite>
```

Comment: The current example does not compile. I tried adjusting it to guess what changes needed to be made but once I got it to compile it doesn't reproduce the issue (i.e. it runs fine for me and does not hang). I changed `new Object[] { 1, "a" }, new Object[] { 2, "b" },` to `return new Object[][]{{1, "a"}, {2, "b"}};` and added `@Test(dataProvider = "data-provider")` to `testProgramOptions(Integer, String)`. If you can update your example to compile I'll try again.

Comment: I moved class level members baseurl , severity declaration in test method testProgramOptions , now test does not hang.

Comment: Is InheritableThreadLocal<>() the appropriate way to use webdriver parallely in methods?

Comment: That simply depends on how you want to manage your WebDriver instances. If you want a new instance per thread then you run the risk of using some library that creates a new thread and inadvertently causes issues because it uses a separate WebDriver instance. If you want a new instance per test even inherited by child threads then your test can no longer use multiple instances in separate threads without creating a separate way to manage those threads (other than your existing ThreadLocal). It is is simply a matter of tradeoffs.